# ¿Como mantener los objetos de una pagina web estáticos en HTML?

Tags: html

```css
#div1 {
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

.Principal {
    /*background: #F1F1F1;*/
    padding-left: 200px;
    padding-right: 200px;
}

.Encabezado {
    background: #EB0029;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Malgun Gothic';
}

.Merlin {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
}

#table1 {
    background: #4e4044;
}

#Usuario {
    font-family: 'Malgun Gothic';
    font-size: 12px;
    width:750px;
    text-align:left;
    color:white;
}

#Fecha {
    font-family: 'Malgun Gothic';
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    width:250px;
}

#td1 {
    width:500px;
}

#ul1 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    width: 260px;
    font-family: 'Malgun Gothic';
    font-size: 14px;
}

#ul2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    width: 260px;
    font-family: 'Malgun Gothic';
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 187px;
}

li {
    /*float: left;*/
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #4E4044;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Malgun Gothic';
    font-size: 14px;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #EB0029;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<asp:Content runat="server" id="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">

    <div id="div1">
        <table class="Encabezado"> 
            <tr>
                <td><img src="Imagenes/LogoBanorte.jpg" style: height="120px"/></td>
                <td class="Merlin"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="table1">
            <tr>
                <td id="Usuario">Usuario: </td>
                <td id="Fecha">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var today = new Date();
                        var m = today.getMonth() + 1;
                        var mes = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;
                        document.write('Fecha: '+ today.getDate(), '/' + mes, '/' + today.getFullYear());
                    </script>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul id="ul1">
                     <li><a>Administración y Planeación</a></li>
                     <li><a>Consumo Comercial</a></li>
                     <li><a>Contraloria</a></li>
                     <li><a>Empresarial</a></li>
                     <li><a>Inmuebles</a></li>
                     <li><a>Intranet Inmuebles</a></li>
                     <li><a>Jurídico</a></li>
                     <li><a>Proyectos de Inversión</a></li>
                     <li><a>Comunicados DG</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                </td>
                <td id="td1"></td>
                <td>
                    <ul id="ul2">
                     <li><a>Recursos Humanos</a></li>
                     <li><a>Intranet Corporativa</a></li>
                        <li><a>Banorte</a></li>
                        <li><a>Ethics Point, Denuncia Anonima</a></li>
                        <li><a>Encuesta y Resultados</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Esta es mi pagina web:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al mover la ventana hacia la derecha y dejar que adopte el tamaño de la mitad de la pantalla se mueven de lugar los objetos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sin el HTML ni CSS no es posible ayudarte

Comment: Una disculpa, ya agregue el codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el disenio responsive es bastante util hoy en dia, la gente utiliza mas los telefonos inteligentes que un ordenador para navegar en internet, tambien ayuda el SEO, pero es tu decision. Puedes mantenerlo estatico con un max-width y un min-width

```css
#div1 {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    max-width: 1030px;
    min-width: 1030px
}

.Principal {
    /*background: #F1F1F1;*/
    padding-left: 200px;
    padding-right: 200px;
}

.Encabezado {
    background: #EB0029;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Malgun Gothic';
}

.Merlin {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
}

#table1 {
    background: #4e4044;
}

#Usuario {
    font-family: 'Malgun Gothic';
    font-size: 12px;
    width:750px;
    text-align:left;
    color:white;
}

#Fecha {
    font-family: 'Malgun Gothic';
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    width:250px;
}

#td1 {
    width:500px;
}

#ul1 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    width: 260px;
    font-family: 'Malgun Gothic';
    font-size: 14px;
}

#ul2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    width: 260px;
    font-family: 'Malgun Gothic';
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 187px;
}

li {
    /*float: left;*/
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #4E4044;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Malgun Gothic';
    font-size: 14px;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #EB0029;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<asp:Content runat="server" id="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">

    <div id="div1">
        <table class="Encabezado"> 
            <tr>
                <td><img src="Imagenes/LogoBanorte.jpg" style: height="120px"/></td>
                <td class="Merlin"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="table1">
            <tr>
                <td id="Usuario">Usuario: </td>
                <td id="Fecha">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var today = new Date();
                        var m = today.getMonth() + 1;
                        var mes = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;
                        document.write('Fecha: '+ today.getDate(), '/' + mes, '/' + today.getFullYear());
                    </script>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ul id="ul1">
                     <li><a>Administración y Planeación</a></li>
                     <li><a>Consumo Comercial</a></li>
                     <li><a>Contraloria</a></li>
                     <li><a>Empresarial</a></li>
                     <li><a>Inmuebles</a></li>
                     <li><a>Intranet Inmuebles</a></li>
                     <li><a>Jurídico</a></li>
                     <li><a>Proyectos de Inversión</a></li>
                     <li><a>Comunicados DG</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                </td>
                <td id="td1"></td>
                <td>
                    <ul id="ul2">
                     <li><a>Recursos Humanos</a></li>
                     <li><a>Intranet Corporativa</a></li>
                        <li><a>Banorte</a></li>
                        <li><a>Ethics Point, Denuncia Anonima</a></li>
                        <li><a>Encuesta y Resultados</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```